# How to create a transforming class loader

Tags: java, class, classloader, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to make a class loader which transforms the class bytes of the class being loaded using some kind of class transformer.

Suppose I have the following code:

```java
static class Test {
  void foo();
}

void test() {
  ClassLoader transformingLoader = transformingClassLoader(..., this.getClass().getClassLoader(), ...);
  Class<?> klass = Class.forName("test.package.Tests$TestClass", true, loader);

  // I want to use the class easily here, but using it like this
  // will cause it to load a new instance of the class, ignoring the already
  // defined class by the transforming class loader and so all the transformations.
  TestClass test1 = new TestClass();
  test2.foo();

  // Using something like this doesn't work either, it throws a ClassCastException
  // because both classes are different from different loaders
  TestClass test2 = (TestClass) klass.newInstance();
}
```

How could I make this work? I have tried using an interface like:

```java
interface Test {
  void foo();
}

static class TestClass implements Test { 
  // ...
}

void test() {
  ClassLoader transformingLoader = ...
  Class<?> klass = Class.forName("test.package.Tests$TestClass", true, loader);

  // This leads to another ClassCastException though, because the transforming
  // class loader defines it's own version of the Test interface.
  Test test = (Test) klass.newInstance();
  test.foo();
}
```

This is my current code for the transforming class loader: [pastes.dev](https://pastes.dev/8xcOtADf8Y)

So how could I fix these issues?
I think most of the issues would be fixed if the class loader properly used already loaded classes when available but it doesn't seem like it does.

Comment: Don't let the class loader define the `Test` interface. Not sure what you pass as predicate, but it should only be true for `TestClass`.

Comment: Post your full code here as pastes.dev will remove the source someday, and the question will then become useless. (also the full code as asked with predicate, the loader should be the tra,sformingLoader i Guess) Are you sure you need it? For dynamic code on an interface the java.lang.reflect.Proxy class could be enough.

Comment: Why not implement an actual [`ClassFileTransformer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) in the first place?